# How should I load a xib into a detail view for a split view iPad objective app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I've got a split view iPad app with table view in the master pane. After drilling down several levels, each time loading a new .xib, I'd like one of the cells to trigger a web page load in the detail pane. Right now I can only get the web page .xib to load in the master pane side -- which is a master pain in my side.

The basic load call where "URLWindow" is a class loaded with initWithNibName:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:URLWindow animated:YES];
```

I want to do this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
@interface
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DetailViewController *detailViewController;
...
@implementation
[[self detailViewController] pushViewController:URLWindow animated:YES];
```

How should I be loading the URLWindow .xib into a detail view for a split view detail pane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couple of things to check:

1) you may try setting BOTH master / detail controllers as 'UINavigationControllers' ?

2) [`detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:URLWindow animated:YES];`

you are calling pushViewController on 'detailViewController',   this is calling it on 'navigationController'

Comment: please post the fix you went with, so we can all learn too. thanks.